# automatically overwrite old imports with new one in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import, refactoring

I have this problem (laziness on hundreds of files)

I have a project built with Java using Eclipse. In this project, until now, all the classes import other main classes that are in the same project.

Now, I decided to move all the main imported classes to a library project in order to share them with other incoming projects. With the new project, I simply need to import from the classes in the library project ... nice ... here the bad news start for the old project.

Is it possible to tell Eclipse to change all the main classes imported in the old project with the ones in the library project?

Until now, I have only found a solution: deleting old imports and importing the new ones one by one by hand, which takes too long.

Has anyone been in this situation? any advice?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sound to be doing two separate things.

1) Moving the source files into a library project

2) Moving the classes to a different **package**

Do them separately.

First move the files to the new project, update the original projects dependencies to include the library project. Make sure it compiles etc.

Now use eclipse's refactor functionality to move the classes to the desired package. Eclipse will automatically update the imports in all the open projects in your workspace when the classes are moved.

If for some reason your are unable to use eclipse's refactor tools, the old skool way to do this is to find and replace across files. This can be done from eclipse ("find in files, replace", with grep etc or countless other ways.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
What I need is to just put main_classes in a library project, then use that library in the old project and **updating the imports to the new main_classes location (the library project) automatically**

You say:
"update the original projects dependencies to include the library project. Make sure it compiles etc" => that's my problem...it doesn't compile..saying that I'm missing some file (the one I moved to the library project)

Comment: You do not import files - you import classes. If the package the class is located under hasn't changed there is no need to change the import. It sounds as if you have not declared that your project depends on the new library project.

Comment: The library has another fresh new package name.  In my old project I've added the library under _the java build path and in the android options_

Comment: So, as per my answer you are doing two things. You have changed the package name to "a fresh new package name" at the same time as moving the source files. If you do this in steps (i.e move the files without changing the package name, then change the package name with the refactor tool) the imports will be updated without having to do so manually or use find and replace.

Answer (score 0):

Select your project in Project Explorer and press

ctrl + shift + O

This feature is called "Organize Imports" (the main menu: "Source - Organize Imports")

Comment: already tried the automatic import with ctrl+shift+O ..
The problem is that when I delete the main_classes from the project ,  I get Error at compile time "main_class cannot be resolved to a type" in the classes that used that main_class. 

So the classes import the old main_classes, not the new ones...that's exaclty my question

Comment: @vince46 Did you change names of your classes, or just packages they belong to?

Comment: the names are the same, just put in a library project and then I imported the library in the old projet...but the imports point to the old files (logically right)

Comment: @vince46 So you do not need the old files anymore, right?

Comment: yes, now there are no old file for the main_classes in the old project...they are in the /Library project...but the references in the normal classes of the old project still point to the old main_classes...